# How to elegantly assign a function to several object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello JavaScript professionals!

I'm trying to improve my JavaScript knowlegde and would like to ask you what's the most elegant rewrite for the following snippet which dynamically assigns a function to several object properties.

I'm using jQuery but I appreciate non-jQuery solutions, too. Short and readable solutions welcome! Thank you!

```
$.fn.feedback.events = function () {
    var events = ['reset', 'success', 'error', 'warning'],
        r = {};
    $.each(events, function (_, ev) {
        r[ev] = function (evt, msg) {
            $.fn.feedback.displayFeedback(evt.delegateTarget, evt.type, msg);
        };
    });
    return r;
}();
```

With the above snippet I'd like to replace the following construct which is probably the most readable solution but hey we are programmers not writers. :)

```
$.fn.feedback.events = {
    reset: function (evt, msg) {
        $.fn.feedback.displayFeedback(evt.delegateTarget, evt.type, msg);
    },
    success: function (evt, msg) {
        $.fn.feedback.displayFeedback(evt.delegateTarget, evt.type, msg);
    },
    error: function (evt, msg) {
        $.fn.feedback.displayFeedback(evt.delegateTarget, evt.type, msg);
    },
    warning: function (evt, msg) {
        $.fn.feedback.displayFeedback(evt.delegateTarget, evt.type, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: delegation does many event at once without a loop: $(elm).on("reset,success,error,warning", function (evt, msg) { ...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the hint but this question is about the event handlers not about binding them.

I'm binding my events based on the result of the above code snippet by iterating over the set handlers. I like to have just one place where my events are specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're all the same function, so there's no need to create a new function for each one of them:

```
(function () {
    var events = ['reset', 'success', 'error', 'warning'];

    $.fn.feedback.events = {};

    $.each(events, function (_, ev) {
        $.fn.feedback.events[ev] = display;
    });

    function display (evt, msg) {
        $.fn.feedback.displayFeedback(evt.delegateTarget, evt.type, msg);
    }

}());
```